# How to create a status check on Github for lines not covered by test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, github, codecov

is there any way how to create a status check that will fail when some test is missing for added line? I am getting [this warning](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiJMj.png) by Codecov now, but I want to block merge every time when test is missing. I am also using CircleCi as an integration service. Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try and integrate [CircleCI and Codecov](https://www.pixelmatters.com/blog/tutorial-part-2-how-to-integrate-circleci-codecov-into-your-project) (from [Tom Hu](https://circleci.com/blog/author/tom-hu/), Developer Relations Lead at Codecov), in order to use the Codecov orb on the CircleCI config.

Thant would allow to, for instance on GitHub, define a new status check on the branch protection and add a friendly report bot.
Add the status check by accessing again to the projects settings, and add the new tick:

[image: https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3fdb4ac2968afe2a89c98b/5f4d21b75cf2fb31cd7a604e_1_gLMQ5i9M4A7IDNvRD5eNNw.png]

That triggers the installation of the Codecov bot:

[image: https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3fdb4ac2968afe2a89c98b/5f4d21fb3ac1cbd79163d9f5_1_SWpLYbT081xw8iFZvKnobg.png]

And for a certain threshold, it will mean the status check will fail and block the merge:

[image: threshold -- https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3fdb4ac2968afe2a89c98b/5f4d2226f87cc462e29b5e83_1_pvyAaoSRbjYoX6AqxTXumw.png]

Result:

[image: failed check -- https://uploads-ssl.webflow.com/5f3fdb4ac2968afe2a89c98b/5f4d223ab9c0042755846d76_1_kQeST256aAF0KBWK-MNuPg.png]

---

For pure CircleCI pipelines, you also have [condition steps and workflows](https://support.circleci.com/hc/en-us/articles/360043638052-Conditional-steps-in-jobs-and-conditional-workflows).
Said pipeline can send tests result to Codecov, as seen in "[Setting up a CI pipeline with CircleCI](https://dev.to/fabiogallotti/setting-up-a-ci-pipeline-with-circleci-42i)" from [Fabio Gallotti](https://github.com/fabiogallotti).